# Create page in templates for pages or the pages manager?

Tags: php, page-template, performance

In terms of slowness and loading which differences noted in the pages created as a template and created by adminisrtador?

Example template page:

```
<?php
/**
    Template Name: My Page name
*/

.....

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Templates might load faster because they don't have to do a database query, they have already all the text hardcoded in them.

Also, this might not be the right way to do it and you might have problems or conflicts if you are not doing it right. Considering the fact that the speed diference will be very small, I sugest you should go with a page created in the admin manager.